# VLC and Totem crashes immediately while playing H265/HEVC

Tags: video, vlc, totem, hevc

I was trying to play a video of H265 mkv format on ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I try to play the video on totem,the video goes on for a few seconds and then totem crashes.

In VLC,the window crashes immediately.I have installed all the plugins for playing H265 but both of the softwares are not playing the video.

i have installed vlc-plugin-libde265,gstreamer0.10-libde265 and libde265 from
repository ppa:strukturag/libde265

having this problem for x265 codec files only other files play fine on both players.

output of vlc in terminal

```
    crsag@SAG:~$ totem
    VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
    [0x8128190] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
    [0xacd05270] main input error: Invalid PCR value in ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR !
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

output for torem in terminal

```
crsag@SAG:~$ totem
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: run vlc with `-vvv` option to see more output. But segfault should not happen, even if your file is broken.

Comment: @incBrain the file isn't broken in my case... I ran the same file in Windows after upgrading VLC, it is running peacefully... In Ubuntu-14.04, however it is crashing!