# VLC Crashing x265 video despite installing all codecs (14.04, 32bit)

Tags: vlc, codecs, hevc

I have installed the libde plugin and the restricted Ubuntu extras. It crashes immediately on launch whenever I open an x265 file.

I am using the iGPU:

```
description: VGA compatible controller product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 09 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 resources: irq:26 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

When I attempt to open the file through the Terminal I get the error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

[This person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719454/vlc-and-totem-crashes-immediately-while-playing-h265-hevc) also seemed to have had the same problem, with no solution offered.

I ran the plugin configuration reset and got this result. The crash issue persists.

```
:~$ vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1~trusty2)
[08d0a928] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(vlc:3829): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:3829): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:3829): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:3829): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:3829): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```